# Trello Limitations for free accounts?

Tags: trello, online-storage

I have signed up trello few days back and just looking for limitations for the free version. Is there any limitations for the free signup ? And if yes , what are those ? I belong to institute and want to use it for research collaboration. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

For the normal usage of Trello there is absolutely no limitation. With the free version you can create any number of boards, lists and cards.
However there are some extra functions you may decide to subscribe in order to help the team behind Trello and have extra control on your boards:

- Gold account will let you upload attachments bigger than 10MB and change the background image of your boards.
- Business Class subscription will give you further control over your Organization; managing accounts centrally, additional features to integrate with Slack, Github... and all users belonging to your organization becomes automatically Golden.